# Create trigger in oracle doesn't find sequence

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, sequence

I am trying to create a sequence and then use it in a table for auto increment.
I am using Oracle 10g.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ALL_BANK_STMT_SEQ START WITH 1;

CREATE TRIGGER ALL_BANK_STMT_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON ALL_BANK_STMT 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
      SELECT ALL_BANK_STMT_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.BANK_STMT_LN_NO FROM SYS.DUAL;
END;
```

This gives an error ORA-02289 : sequence doesn't exist.

However , when I select from the sequence it work's fine but I can't seem to use it in a trigger i.e. I get results when I do :

```
select ALL_BANK_STMT_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual;
```

Am I missing any permission to use it in the trigger ?

Comment: Seems to work for me-- here's a fiddle that shows it working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffa3da1671c9eccb7d60c9511e315ad5  My guess is that you've got a typo somewhere in your actual code (i.e. you're misspelling the sequence name) or that the GUI isn't actually running the statement you think you're running.

Comment: There is no need to select the sequence, you can just employ simple assignment.   **:new.bank_stmt_ln_no  := all_bank_stmt_seq.nextval;**

Comment: Is it possible that the sequence is a synonym to another schema? Because then it might be a genuine privs issue, because if you have acces via a role and not directly, then you will the anomaly (works in sqlplus but not in plsql)